# Prevenir el complemento a dos en javascript

Tags: javascript, binario, hexadecimal, complemeto-a-dos

Estoy haciendo un programa con binarios de 32 bits, pero javascript me calcula el complemento a dos de el número de 32 bits, y me gustaría que no lo hiciera.

Ejemplo

```js
let a = 0x0 ^ 0xEDB88320;

/* ====================
// 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
// 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
// ---------------------------------------------------------------   -> XOR
// 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

Número que ofrece js: -306674912


Y quiero que me convierta el binario en su numero decimal sin complemento a dos: 3988292384

======================*/
```

En python me sale lo que quiero, pero en js me hace la conversión a complemento a dos

```
a = 0x0 ^ 0xEDB88320

# Output: 3988292384
```

Y quiero exactamente lo que me hace python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estás haciendo el cálculo con datos **numéricos** gigantes:

```js
let a = 0x0;
let b = 0xEDB88320;

console.log(typeof(a));
console.log(typeof(b));
```

Tendrías que agregar **`n`** al final de los números para convertirlo a [**`BigInt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```js
let a = 0x0n;
let b = 0xEDB88320n;

console.log(typeof(a));
console.log(typeof(b));
```

y el cálculo sería:

```js
let a = 0x0n ^ 0xEDB88320n;
console.log(Number(a))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! También encontré la forma con `(0x0 ^ 0xEDB88320) >>> 0`